# How could I test if two bit patterns differs in any N bits (position doesn't matter)

Tags: comparison, bit

Let's say i have this bit field value: `10101001`

How would i test if any other value differs in any `n` bits. Without considering
the positions?

Example:

```
10101001
10101011 --> 1 bit different 

10101001
10111001 --> 1 bit different

10101001
01101001 --> 2 bits different

10101001
00101011 --> 2 bits different
```

I need to make a lot of this comparisons so i'm primarily looking for perfomance but any
hint is very welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take the XOR of the two fields and do a population count of the result.

Comment: Even though the question does point out how many bits are different, as far as I read it, it asks only to tell if two values differ at *some* bit position, not how many bit positions are different.  If this reading is correct, you don't need the final population count, just a straight check for non-zero.

Answer (score 5):

if you XOR the 2 values together, you are left only with the bits that are different.

You then only need to count the bits which are still 1 and you have your answer

in c:

```
 unsigned char val1=12;
 unsigned char val2=123;
 unsigned char xored = val1 ^ val2;
 int i;
 int numBits=0;
 for(i=0; i<8; i++)
 {
      if(xored&1) numBits++;
      xored>>=1;
 }
```

although there are probably faster ways to count the bits in a byte
(you could for instance use a lookuptable for 256 values)

Answer (score 4):

Just like everybody else said, use XOR to determine what's different and then [use one of these algorithms to count](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).

Comment: See also: http://gurmeetsingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/fast-bit-counting-routines/

Answer (score 3):

This gets the bit difference between the values and counts the bits three at a time:

```
public static int BitDifference(int a, int b) {
   int cnt = 0, bits = a ^ b;
   while (bits != 0) {
      cnt += (0xE994 >> ((bits & 7) << 1)) & 3;
      bits >>= 3;
   }
   return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XOR the numbers, then the problem becomes a matter of counting the 1s in the result.

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
Integer.bitCount(a ^ b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison is performed with XOR, as others already answered.

counting can be performed in several ways:

- shift left and addition.
- lookup in a table.
- logic formulas that you can find with [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).